# Web API action names

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing with ASP.NET Web API and I have the following:

```
public Guid GetLogon(string username, string password)
{
    return new X.Authentication().Logon(username, password);
}

public void PostLogoff(Guid sessionId)
{
    new X.Authentication().Logoff(sessionId);
}
```

This is being called from the client side as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    logon("MyUsername", "MyPassword", function (guid) {
        $("#sessionId").html(guid);

        logoff($("#sessionId").html(), function () {
            //Logged out action here
        });
    });        
});
```

This all works, but I don't like to have to prefix the Action names with the http verb, like GetLogon or PostLogoff. Is there a way to make them just Logon and Logoff?

I tried the following, which didn't work:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public Guid Logon(string username, string password)
{
    return new X.Authentication().Logon(username, password);
}

[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public void Logoff(Guid sessionId)
{
    new X.Authentication().Logoff(sessionId);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Doesn't work?? What was the outcome?  A 404 Not Found? 500 Server Error?

Comment: Request GET /api/Authentication/Logon?username=MyUsername&password=MyPassword HTTP/1.1 

Response HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: How are your calling logon as a function rather than an explicit jquery api call. Do you have a framework that is building your methods? or are you just using that as shorthand.

Comment: Those javascript logon and logoff functions make explicit jquery get or post to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause, but in my APIController the AcceptVerbs attribute is in a different namespace:

```
System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs
```

The `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attribute are in the same namespace

I have a number of regular MVC controllers in the same project; they use the namespace you have described above, but not the API Controllers

Try this:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public Guid Logon(string username, string password)
{
    return new X.Authentication().Logon(username, password);
}

[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void Logoff(Guid sessionId)
{
    new X.Authentication().Logoff(sessionId);
}
```

Comment: It worked like this: [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]. I'm not sure in which namespace is your HttpVerbs.Get, I couldn't get it to work with System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs, it expects an array of strings.

Comment: I accepted your answer because the change of namespace did the trick, even though the HttpVerbs.Get didn't work. Thanks for the reply ;)

Comment: Great glad you got it working, I updated the Answer for those who come after!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API will try to *guess* the method if you **start** the action name with Get, Post, Put or Delete. For example:

```
public void DeleteItem(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Will work and system will find out that it will be triggered by DELETE.

As a backward compatibility, `[HttpGet]` etc attributes are supported.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but you didn't really answer my question. I know it will try to match based on the method name, but seems awkward to have a method PostLogoff. Logoff with an attribute marking it for Post seems cleaner imho.

Comment: @Dante I did mention attributes at the end of my answer.